# I can't send text from textbox HttpRequest c#

Tags: c#, httprequest

I've try this and it is OK.

But textbox can't send text. `text is null`

```
    {
        //Thread chiadoanduoi2000 = new Thread(chiadoanduoi200);
        //chiadoanduoi2000.Start();
        //  chiadoanduoi2000.IsBackground = true;
        string doanDuoi2000 = textBox1.Text;
        HttpRequest http = new HttpRequest();
        http.AddHeader("apikey", "xxx");
        http.AddParam("input", "soem text here");
        http.AddParam("speed", "1.0");
        http.AddParam("encode_type", "0");
        http.AddParam("speaker_id", "3");
        string auido = http.Post("https://api.zalo.ai/v1/tts/synthesize").ToString();
        
        textBox1.Text = auido;
        textBox2.Text = auido;
        //File.WriteAllText("truyen.txt", outputTexts[i].ToString());
    }
```

but can't send text from textbox to request api

```
{
        //Thread chiadoanduoi2000 = new Thread(chiadoanduoi200);
        //chiadoanduoi2000.Start();
        //  chiadoanduoi2000.IsBackground = true;
        string doanDuoi2000 = textBox1.Text;
        HttpRequest http = new HttpRequest();
        http.AddHeader("apikey", "xxx");
        http.AddParam("input", doanDuoi2000);
        http.AddParam("speed", "1.0");
        http.AddParam("encode_type", "0");
        http.AddParam("speaker_id", "3");
        string auido = http.Post("https://api.zalo.ai/v1/tts/synthesize").ToString();
        
        textBox1.Text = auido;
        textBox2.Text = auido;
        //File.WriteAllText("truyen.txt", outputTexts[i].ToString());
    }
```

Please help me, thanks very much.

Comment: Are you getting an error or anything like that?

Comment: Where do you set the value for textBox1?  Is it being set to what you think it is?  What is doanDuoi2000 when you make the call?

Answer (score 0):

Providing textBox1.Text is a textbox control, by default after creation, the Text value will return string.empty.

Ensure there is call along the lines of

textbox1 = new Textbox();

This is normally handled in you . designer file for the form.